# Observable subscription error after rxjs update

Tags: angular, rxjs

This piece of code was working fine

```js
export function appInitializer(accountService: AccountService) {
    return () => new Promise(resolve => {
        // attempt to refresh token on app start up to auto authenticate
        accountService.refreshToken()
            .subscribe()
            .add(resolve);
    });
}
```

but now after updating rxjs from version 6.5.5 to 7.4.0, I have this error when I add *resolve* to the *Subscription* :

> (parameter) resolve: (value: unknown) => void
> Argument of type '(value: unknown) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TeardownLogic'.
> Type '(value: unknown) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'.ts(2345)
> app.initializer.ts(8, 18): Did you mean to call this expression?

The angular project I am trying to modify is available [here](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/08/29/angular-10-boilerplate-email-sign-up-with-verification-authentication-forgot-password)

My noob question is: How can I get this code to work again without having to go back to rxjs v6.5.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
accountService.refreshToken()
        .subscribe()
        .add(()=>resolve());
```

or even better

```
export function appInitializer(accountService: AccountService) {
    return () => new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        // attempt to refresh token on app start up to auto authenticate
        accountService.refreshToken().subscribe(()=>resolve,err=>reject(err))
    });
```

}

But this is how I would probably do it

```
export function appInitializer(accountService: AccountService) {
    return () => accountService.refreshToken()
    }
```

Here you have a working demo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gl1dnd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

check the console, it shows that both initializers are running on startup

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach is to use [firstValueFrom](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/firstValueFrom):

```js
import { Observable, firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

interface AccountService {
  refreshToken: () => Observable<unknown>
}

export function appInitializer(accountService: AccountService) {
    return () => firstValueFrom(accountService.refreshToken());
}
```